# Redirecting after submit with counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to redirect with counter to another page. I want the redirect to start when I have submit the form. I want to redirect to another page after submit form.

```js
var count = 6;
var redirect = "https://www.google.com";

function countDown() {
  var timer = document.getElementById("timer");
  if (count > 0) {
    count--;
    timer.innerHTML = "This page will redirect in " + count + " seconds.";
    setTimeout("countDown()", 1000);
  } else {
    window.location.href = redirect;
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <p>
    <label>Name
      <input type="text" name="textfield">
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"><br>
</form>

<span id="timer">
  <script type="text/javascript">countDown();</script>
</span>

</p>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. If you want to submit when the form is submit, what's the point of the (broken) counter?

Comment: i want the redirect to display after submit form. like if i enter name then click submit then redirect comes. instead redirecting when haven't filled in and submit the form

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: How is sent your form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A form submit is always a request to the server. You can either use ajax to perform the submission of the form or you can just count and submit the form afterwards.

To prevent your form from submitting when a user hits the button u can prevent the default behaviour like so:

```
$('input [type=submit]').on('click', function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // use your counter here
    // when counter hits 0 just submit the form with
    $('form').submit();
});
```

or use an ajax call:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url/to/form/action',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        method: "POST",
        success: function() {
            // start your counter
            // REDIRECT
        }
    });
});
```

The Problem with the first method would be that you are just delaying the form submission.
In the second case u cant reliably tell when you will get an success (or error) response since the call is asynchrous. This will result in either a delay before your counter starts or a possible delay after your counter ends if the server didnt respond until then.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a counter by using setInterval, and making a check until it hits 0 to redirect:

```html
<form method="post">
  <p>
    <label>Name
  <input type="text" name="textfield">
  </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
    <br>
</form>

<span id="timer">This page will redirect in <span id="count"></span> second(s).</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var count = 6;
  var redirect = "https://www.google.com";
  var elem = document.getElementById('count');
  elem.innerText = count
  
  setInterval(() => {
    count--
    elem.innerText = count
    if (count == 0) {
      window.location.href = redirect;
    }
  }, 1000)
</script>
```

Comment: this is same thing.  i want the redirect to display after submit form. like if i enter name the click submit then redirect comes. instead redirecting when haven't filled in and submit the form

Comment: Submitting a form will make a request to your server, so you cannot invoke a redirect after submitting a form.

Comment: i understand. ok